# Spring boot custom login page for single page web application

Tags: javascript, java, rest, spring-boot, authentication

I'm working on a single web page application by using Spring boot. The application integrates the Spring security layer so when I run the application it shows a login page.

I would change that login page with a custom one, however in order to do this i have to set all configuration params to spring boot.

I was able to change the default login page with the one made by me but the login doesn't work, here it is my config class:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
         //   .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.html")
            .successForwardUrl("/index.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
}


@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("jaeger")
            .password("asd").roles("USER");
}

}
```

And this is the html page for the login:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body onload='document.f.username.focus();'>
<h3>Login with Username and Password jajajaaaajjaja</h3><form name='f' action='/login' method='POST'>
<table>
  <tr><td>UserAA:</td><td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='password'/></td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/></td></tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When i press the login button it seems that nothing is happening, so my question is if i can create my own login service and manage the login directly by my self.

Thank you

Comment: How are you passing (_controlling_) _model_ (java data) to _view_ (html stuff)?

Comment: I only use API REST